# Can't connect to SQL Server locally

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 installation on my local system, and the following code in C#, in .NET 4.5.

```
    private Boolean ConnectDatabase()
    {
        if( !this.IsInitialized())
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                String ConnectionString = "User ID=" + this.DatabaseUsername + ";" +
                                            "Password=" + this.DatabasePassword + ";" +
                                            "Server=" + this.DatabaseHost + "," + this.DatabasePort + ";" +
                                            "Database=" + this.DatabaseResource + ";";
                this.DatabaseConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
                this.DatabaseConnection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I can connect to the server in SSMS, but using the same credentials I am unable to get a connection in C#.

Connection string is as follows:

```
User ID=sa;Password=******;Server=CPUNAME\MSSQL,1433;Database=DBNAME;
```

Where `CPUName`, `DBName`, and ****** are replaced with their appropriate values. I've also tried using Windows Credentials, and a variety of different server endpoints, including my NB Name, Loopback IP, Static internal IP, blah blah blah. Firewall is OFF. TCP is enabled on the server.

I get the following exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: is it sqlexpress database ??

Comment: Negative. SQL Server Enterprise. Services are running.

Comment: I suspect that your SERVER part is not correct. Try with (LOCAL) or just the name of your computer.

Comment: I've tried 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', and 'ATLANTIS' ( NB - resolves ); as well as a static interal IP.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Did you enable a protocol in the SQL Server Configuration Manager?</s>

See [Enable TCP/IP Network Protocol for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx)

*[Edit]*
Nevermind; I missed the "TCP is enabled on the server" part ;-)
The question then becomes: Did you **restart** SQL server after enabling TCP/IP? You need to restart the SQL service ([see step 6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231672.aspx)) for these changes to become effective.

Also verify you're using the correct instancename (You're currently using `MSSQL` as instancename, this might be `SQLExpress` or something).

Comment: Correct instance name, computer has been rebooted like four times.

Comment: And CPUName resolves to the correct host? (Try a `ping CPUName` for example). Port is also verified to actually be 1433? Also you might want to take a look at [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/12/19/provider-tcp-provider-error-0-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it.aspx); it mentions that there could be an `alias` in place causing the wrong host to be resolved.

Comment: I verified in the configuration manager that the port is set to the default of 1433. I can also assure you that CPUName resolves.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of services that have to be running in order to connect, even locally. Some of these (helpfully) are set to "manual start" by default. Services you might want to check include the SQL Server, SQL Server Agent and the Distributed Transaction Coordinator.

Comment: All SQL related services are running, as well as the DTC.